# Create a card token in Stripe via API POSTMAN

Tags: api, stripe-payments, postman

I am creating some API for stripe payment. I try to create API to getting card token for payment. below is my code

**Postman Data**

```
Request Method: POST,
Request URL: https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens
```

**Headers Data**

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:Bearer SECRET_KEY
```

**Body** 
x-www-form-urlencoded

```
card:{"exp_month":12,"exp_year":2020,"number":'4242424242424242',"cvc":'123'}
```

**Response (Output)**

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "You must pass full card details to create a token.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}
```

Postman screenshots:

**Headers**

[image]

**Body**

[image]

Comment: That JSON looks a little malformed. strings must all be in double quotes and the whole thing should be wrapped in curly brackets. Try this: `{"card":{"exp_month":12,"exp_year":2020,"number":"4242424242424242","cvc":"123"}}
`

Comment: @tshimkus :- Yes, I check this but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you try with content-type as "application/json"?

Comment: Can you add an image of how you have this added in Postman please?

Comment: @DannyDainton :- yes, let me update

Comment: @DannyDainton: I have updated Question. Please check and save my day

Comment: Couple of things, please update Postman. Missing out on lot's of things. Flip to the key/value view and add those values into the form. The syntax you're using isn't correct for that bulk edit view. Should be `key:value` on new lines.

Comment: As a general point you should almost never do this, as passing card numbers in this way increases your [PCI scope](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance). If you want to have a token for testing and creating charges, you can just use `tok_visa` and friends from Stripe's [testing page](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)

Comment: @karllekko yes, your right

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I imported the cURL request from the [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card) documentation into Postman. This request should look like this one below.

[image: Postman]

Once, you add the Auth Token into the `header` - It should then allow you to create the card token (If everything else is ok)

Just for reference, the syntax for the `key/value` view, should look like this and not like you have it in your request.

[image: Syntax]